# how to use one function of a script in another script in unity using c#

Tags: c#, function, object, unity-game-engine, reference

i am making a game in unity with c#
i wanted to use a function of a script in another script

1st script name player controller

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector2 moving = new Vector2();
public int Bulletlimit = 0;
public int MaxBulletlimit = 3;

public Bullet bullet;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    moving.x = moving.y = 0;

    if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
        moving.x = 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
        moving.x = -1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
        moving.y = 1;
    } else if (Input.GetKey ("down")) {
        moving.y = -1;
    }


    if (Input.GetKey ("s")) {

        BulletShot();   
}   

}

public void BulletShot(){
    if(Bulletlimit < MaxBulletlimit)
    {
        Bullet clone = Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Bullet;
        Bulletlimit = Bulletlimit + 1;
    }
}


public void BulletCount()
{
    Bulletlimit = Bulletlimit - 1;
}
}
```

2nd script name Bullet Destroy

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class BulletDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

private Player player;
private PlayerController playerController;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        }
}
}
```

how do i call the BulletCount function from playercontroller script to BulletDestroy Script in the if condition

Comment: playerController.BulletCount();

Comment: In the onStart of BulletDestroy you must write playerController = GetComponent<PlayerController>(); UNLESS you are setting it in the editor.

Comment: i tried that but it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Ogen: regarding your closed question, It again means that you've got an XY Problem -- you're trying to solve the **wrong** problem. Tell us your problem domain, not how you're trying to solve it, and we can help you. Or you can delete your question, and then we can't. Wasting my breathe, I can see....

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it was the wrong problem, that's why i deleted it. Thanks for following up though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this the efficient C# way or the Mono Way which is recommended for beginners if they don't know all the C# procedures.

1st is by inhering from another Class. Which I will not discuss because it may give you some problem in the future, if you don't know how to it works.

2nd is one is by Getting the Component from the Player. If in your game, the player is tagged as a Player then let us use that reference. Or at lease the name of the Player GameObject.

```
PlayerController myCharactersScript;
void Start(){
     myCharactersScript = GameObject.Find("myCharactersName").GetComponent<PlayersController>();


}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
    Destroy (gameObject);
   myCharactersScript.BulletCount();
}

}
```

I suggest for you to read about Inheritance for good coding practice as it is one of the Main Core of C#. FYI you can only Inherit once.